# want to use string as a variable name

Tags: python, string, variables

I am using python

```
a5 = [1.1,1.3,15.4,13.3]
# and 
numb = 5
aname = str('a')+str(numb) 
print(aname[0])
```

I want to make variable name using str and number and then want to get value of that variable

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think this question is duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are global, then you can use `globals()[aname]` to get their value. If they are local, then use `locals()[aname]`

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Dictionary

```
name = "a"
value = True
a_dictionary = {name: value}
print(a_dictionary["a"])
```

the output will be True

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the `eval` function ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)).

For your example:

```py
a5 = [1.1,1.3,15.4,13.3]
# and 
numb = 5
aname = eval('a' + str(numb))
print(aname[0])
```